# Add sucsess message after uninstalling process in advanced installer

Tags: dialog, uninstallation, advanced-installer

I created a setup file for my project with advanced installer but when i try to uninstall the package from control panel i don't see any dialog showing up telling me that uninstallation is a success, it's just run, uninstalling the application and then close. how can i add a dialog to show after uninstallation process?
I'm using advanced installer 12.3.1 and I'm using a custom theme if that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your MSI uninstallation through Control Panel goes in Basic UI mode.

There are several ways to do what you want:

- If you need simple end success or failure dialog:
  you need to create a custom action which will change `INSTALLUILEVEL` to `INSTALLUILEVEL_BASIC` and `INSTALLUILEVEL_ENDDIALOG`. Please refer these links to find more information about it: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370389(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368791(v=vs.85).aspx)
- The second way is a trick to hide **Uninstall** button from Add\Remove Programs and left only **Change** button. Then you need hide Change and Modify buttons from Maintenance dialog window in `AdvancedInstaller` (`InstallShield`, `Orca`, `InstEd`, etc). In this case you will receive uninstallation in Full UI mode.

Comment: thanks for your answer i'll test these as soon as possible and report it back.